# Passing object from controller into view - anonymous type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm messing around while learning, trying to implement some functions of games I've played before. Now struggling where the aspect of having a button that upgrades a certain "item" in the game.

I have a view `details` with a button that calls a function `CallUpgradeField` inside the controller `PlayersController`. The calling of the method works well. But then I want to return the same, updated view. Which is a struggle.

I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[Alan.Models.Player]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Alan.Models.Player'.
```

The button (which works like it's supposed to)

```
@Html.ActionLink("CallUpgradeField", "CallUpgradeField", "Players",new { resourceFieldId = resourceField.ResourceFieldId }, htmlAttributes:null )
                <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("CallUpgradeField", "Players")'" /></td>
```

The controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        var players = _context.Player
            .Include(villages => villages.Villages)
            .ThenInclude(resourceField => resourceField.ResourceFields)
            .ToList();

        if (id == null || players == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var player = players
            .First(m => m.PlayerId == id);

        if (player == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var playerData = _context.PlayerData
            .First(p => p.PlayerDataId == player.PlayerId);

        player.PlayerData = playerData;

        _context.Villages.Include(x => x.VillageData).ToList();

        UpdatePlayerResources(player.Villages);

        var villages = player.Villages.ToList();
        var test = villages[0].ResourceFields
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ResourceFieldId == 1);

        return View(player);
    }
```

And lastly the method

```
        public ActionResult CallUpgradeField(int resourceFieldId)
        {
            ResourceField resourceField = _context.ResourceField.Single(x => x.ResourceFieldId == resourceFieldId);
            Village village = _context.Villages.Single(y => y.VillageId == resourceField.VillageId);
            VillageData villageData = _context.VillageData.Single(z => z.VillageDataId == village.VillageId);
            var playerId = village.PlayerId;
            var player = _context.Player.Single(a => a.PlayerId == playerId);

            village.VillageData = villageData;
            resourceField.Village = village;


            resourceField.UpgradeField();
            return View("Details", new { Player = player });
        }
```

So the view error tells me the model needs an 'Alan.Models.Player'. The thing is when I debug and check the value of 'player' that's exactly what it is. I have no idea whatsoever where '<>f__AnonymousType0`1 is coming from, or how to get away from it. Google searches have led me nowhere in all honesty.

How do I pass an object into the view without making it an AnonymousType in this scenario?

Comment: `new { Player = player }` is of type `<>f__AnonymousType0'1[Alan.Models.Player]` ... what about passing there instance of `Player` there ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant, but I solved it from there. It was the new keyword that screwed it up. return View("Details", player ); works!

Comment: @linkedby thats what selvin meant though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem seemed to lie in the new keyword.

```
return View("Details", player );
```

Works! Thanks @Selvin for the answer.